# Lebesgue integrability of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable, $f(0)=0$ and assume that $f'(0)$ exists. Show that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I don't know what to do. The claim makes sense to me because the only point where one can get an issue is $x=0$ but at $x$ approaches to 0, the function (which is the difference quotient at 0) approaches $f'(0)$ which exists so is finite. But I don't know how to write down a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for $x\in [0,\delta]$ we have a constant bound

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{x} \right| < |f'(0)| + \epsilon$$

On $[\delta , \infty)$ we have an integrable bound

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{x} \right| < \frac{1}{\delta}|f(x)|$$

By the [comparison test for integrability](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-comparison-test-for-lebesgue-integrability),  the Lebesgue integrals of $x \mapsto\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist over both $[0,\delta]$ and $[\delta, \infty)$, and, hence, over $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! And similar for the integral from $(-\infty, 0]$ right?

Comment: @mathstackuser: You're welcome. Yes the argument is the same on the negative real axis.  We have $|f(x)|/|x| < |f(x)|/\delta$ and $|f|$ absolutely integrable on $(-\infty,-\delta]$ as well